# Page transitions in default mode in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to execute a simple jquery mobile code. I just linked two pages. But everytime I am switching from one page to another, it is happening in default mode.Even after mentioning data-transition = 'pop'..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>This is my first jquery mobile programme</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role = "page" id="first">
   <div data-role = "header" >
       <h1>hello world !!</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role = "content">
       <p>This is the content part</p>
       <p><a href ="#second" data-tansition = "pop" > Go to second page </a></p>
   </div>
   <div data-role ="footer">
       <h4>Footer</h4>
   </div>   
</div>

<div data-role = "page" id="second">
    <div data-role ="header">
        <h1>hello Praveen !!</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role ="content">
        <p> this is the second page</p>
        <p><a href =#first> Go to first page </a></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role = "footer">
        <h4>footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have a typo in your markup.

Change

```
data-tansition="pop"
```

to

```
data-transition="pop"
```